# How to set editable pushpins on bing map?

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Drawing Tools Sample</title>

  <!-- Bing Map Control references -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetMap() {

      map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
        credentials: "",
        zoom: 17,
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.592, -122.332)
      });

      var infoboxOptions = {
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        showCloseButton: true,
        zIndex: 0,
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10, 0),
        showPointer: true
      };
      var defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), infoboxOptions);
      map.entities.push(defaultInfobox);
      defaultInfobox.setHtmlContent('<div>MY TEXT <input type="text"></div>');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="GetMap()">
  <div style="position:relative;width:250px;height:150px;float:left;">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative; width:600px;height:200px;"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am looking add custom Html elements such as textbox, textarea to bing map pushpin therefore it can be editable when it placed.
problem is can be place push pin with textbox or textarea but it cannot be editable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the default infobox class. You can work around this by using the custom infobox module found here: https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control